# SQL Server stored procedures to link and unlink records, but also recursively add links?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Background**

I have a table `Person` to represent people:

```
PersonID  |  FirstName  |  LastName
1         |  John       |  Smith
2         |  Jane       |  Smith
3         |  Gary       |  Smith
4         |  Susan      |  Smith
```

... and a table `SiblingLink` to represent siblings (links between people):

```
Person1ID    |  Person2ID
1            |  2
2            |  1
```

A stored procedure called `AddSibling` takes 2 parameters (`@Person1` and `@Person2`) and does an `INSERT` for `Person1 -> Person2` and `Person2 -> Person1`.

This is great when there are only 2 siblings (in this example, John and Jane are now linked together through this table). The removal is also straightforward.

**Problem**

However, I need to expand this procedure to handle the case where `Gary (3)` and `Jane (2)` are linked, because now since `John (1)` is a sibling of `Jane (2)`, he needs to also be a sibling of `Gary (3)`.

```
Person1ID    |  Person2ID
1            |  2
2            |  1
==== NEW RECORDS ========
3            |  2
2            |  3
1            |  3
3            |  1
```

**Question**

What's the proper way for the stored procedure to follow this recursively to add the siblings-of-siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query to find the missing link between two records.  This query looks up pairs of siblings `sl1, sl2` who share a third sibling `sl3` but where there is not yet a direct relation between the first and the third sibling:

```
select  sl1.Person1ID
,       sl2.Person2ID
from    SiblingLink sl1
join    SiblingLink sl2
on      sl1.Person2ID = sl2.Person1ID
        and sl1.Person1ID <> sl2.Person2ID
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    siblingLink sl3
        where   sl3.Person1ID = sl1.Person1ID
                and sl3.Person2ID = sl2.Person2ID
        )
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70d03/7/0)

You can insert the missing sibling.  In a stored procedure, you can use a `while` loop to repeat that until there are no new inserts:

```
while 1=1
  begin
  ...insert query here...

  if @@rowcount = 0
    break
  end
```